# Tabla HTML con este formato

Tags: html, html5

[image: Necesito que en HTML me quedé igualí]
Hola a todos, aquí he podido solucionar muchas de mis dudas, estoy terminando una web y necesito lograr la tabla con el formato que está en la imagen.

Agradezco su colaboración!

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor edita y muéstranos que llevas

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Este sería un ejemplo de la tabla que buscas con una sola línea de detalle.

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <style>
        table {            
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }       
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>            
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Contribution in USD</th>
                <th colspan="3">Benefits</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Time License</th>
                <th>Renewal</th>
                <th>Plan Re-seller% discount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Añadir usando el <tr> de abajo, tantas lineas como necesites -->
            <tr>
                <td>150-200</td>
                <td>12 months</td>
                <td>Monthly renewal</td>
                <td>20%</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenida a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que se más específico en su pregunta y luego procedemos a responder. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.